# How to get image name from uri in marshmallow?

Tags: android

I have a uri and i'm trying to get file name from uri. My uri looks like  content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A52530.

I tried this I, it won't work!

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

            if(data!=null){
                   Uri uri = data.getData();
                   File f = new File("" + uri);

                  f.getName();
            }
}
```

output of this code is image%3A52530.and I want real name of file .

Comment: There is no "real name of file", because there is no file. You can attempt to get a "display name" -- the easiest way to do that is [via `DocumentFile` and its `getName()` method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/provider/DocumentFile.html#getName()). However, it may give you the exact same value back that you are seeing.

Comment: @CommonsWare getName gives me name like " image%3A52530"

Comment: If that is what you are getting from `DocumentFile`, then that is what the document provider is offering as a display name. Since the document provider is the one providing the document, the only name you can get is what it gives you.

Comment: @CommonsWare is there any way for geting name like "abc.png"

Comment: If `DocumentFile` is not giving you `abc.png` as the result of `getName()`, then no, there is no way to get `abc.png`.

Comment: @CommonsWare can i achieve "abc.png" using  real path??

Comment: As noted in my answer on your duplicate question, **there is no real path**.

Comment: @CommonsWare ok! but my problem is i want to make image backup in any sd card public folder becouse of this reason i want same name name of image

Comment: That is not going to be possible, in any reliable fashion.

Comment: @CommonsWare can u please tell me how can i achive this??